# Visual Studio 2015 designer.cs file gets all custom components removed

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on an ASP.net WebForms project. When I save a .aspx page the .designer file gets regenerated but it removes all references to any custom component on the page (ex: ) and leaves intact the references to any default built-in .net components (ex:  ).

The problem is only happening on my machine. The other team members do not have this issue so I know there is not something wrong with the project itself.

One thing I have found is that any time I add or remove an extension in visual studio, it shows the Restart button. When I click that button to restart VS, then the problem with the designer files goes away. But as soon as I manually close VS using the X at the top right, and restart it, that is when the problem comes back.

I've tried with and without using Run as Administrator with no luck either way.